# Flutter app : IOS emulator not connecting to Android Studio

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

In flutter development I want to connect iOS emulator to the android studio.

when I open iOS emulator from android studio It will open but app not run. It give error like "No connected devices."

Project is run from Xcode but from AndroidStidio in will not run

Which version I Use:
1) macOS Mojave-10.14.5 
2) AndroidStudio-3.4
3) Xcode-10.3
4) FlutterSDK-1.7.8
5) Dart-2.4

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Follow below steps

Open Xcode

```
Xcode -> Preference -> Locations -> Command Line Tools
```

Select Xcode `your_xcode_version`

Now go to Android studio and run `flutter doctor`

Hope this one resolve your issue.

Comment: Although it didn't fix my issue directly, going through these steps highlighted the fact that my CocoaPods installation was broken; I had two versions of Ruby, and CocoaPods was installed under the wrong one. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to execute `flutter doctor` command in your terminal to get more details on the issue ?

Comment: yes I try that flutter doctor command and then I also tried that rest of command which given by flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

you shoud path android studio
select target sdk for exmple sdk version 28

> file -> project structure ->project -> project-sdk

select api version sdk

screen shot of select

[image]